# Data archiving strategy for CouchDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, bigdata, couchdb, object-storage, amazon-glacier

**BACKGROUND**:
CouchDB has enormous benefits where most of the developers fall in love with CouchDB like I did. However when it comes to data archiving there are not much resources/features are available out in the open. Open source version seems to be missing these essential features.

Every database grow with time and for those who collect data as a resource, Keeping years of data on couchDB instances with replication on can be a very cost inefficient solution. For example if we host the couchDB on an 
EC2 instances database growth can be a costly solution over time.

**ISSUE**:
There is no point of keeping the years old data in couchDB since there not accessed frequently. Also this cause the view indexing time to go up exponentially for a large data set. For this best solution that I could think of is offloading the some of this years old data into cost effective storage mediums.

**CATCH**: However these data need be retrieved on demand. ex: to see a trends over the years or get the sum all transaction for last 10 years etc..

These are some few approaches that I could think of.

1. Store the partitioned couchDB JSON documents in a low cost storage
   medium such as amazon Glacier with and retrieve data on demand.
   However in order to perform a map-reduce on this data we needed to
   reload the data into CouchDB, which is very inefficient
2. Partition the old data load into S3 and query using AWS Athena,
   However with approach map-reduce can not be achieved. This is only
   for querying data.

I'm sure couchDB users has face this issue in at one point. What other solutions / approaches are out there? Appreciate your help.